# CFG and PDA for the set of strings in $\{a, b, c\}^∗$ such that the number of b’s is equal to the sum of number of a’s and c’s

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I'm trying to find the CFG and PDA for the above language. I have so far come up with this
$S \to S_1S_2 \\ S_1 \to aS_1b \\ S_2 \to bS_2c$
However, I realized that this is just a subset of the required language. How do I consider the remaining ones? Also, how do I construct a PDA for it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the exercise for the same language, but without the letter $c$?

Answer (score 1):

For the PDA, I think you use the stack to track the number of A plus the number of C minus the number of B seen so far, using both positive and negative tokens:

- If the stack is empty and you see an A or a C, you push a "+1" token.
- If the stack is empty and you see a B, you push a "-1" token.
- If the stack is not empty and you see the kind of token that's already on there (e.g. you have a +1 token and you see an A or a C), then you push another of the same token.
- If the stack is not empty and you see the wrong kind of token (e.g. there's a "-1" token on the stack and you see an A or a C), you pop one token.

Depending on your formalisation of PDA you may want to start off by pushing a "zero" token in order to check whether the stack is "logically empty" or not.

The stack keeps the invariant that there can never be both a "+1" and a "-1" token on it at the same time.

The word is in the language if and only if the stack is (logically) empty at the end of the string.